# Find Limits of Composition in the graph of $f$

Tags: limits

The graph of the function $f$ is shown in the figure above. The value of $ \lim_\limits{x\to 0} f(1-x^2) $ is

[image]

When I try to solve this, I get $f(1)$, which should equal $2$. However, the answer key states that it should equal $3$.

Comment: Sorry for the terrible formatting, I don't know how to do format well

Comment: It’s quite good, let use a more concise title as for example “Determine a limit from the given graph of f(x)” and write the present title inbthe OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for $x\approx 0$ we have that

- $1-x^2\le 1$

and $1-x^2\to 1$ as $x\to 0$ then

$$\lim_{x\to 0} f(1-x^2)=\lim_{x\to 1^-} f(x)$$

Note also that the function is not continuos at $x=1$ snce

$$\lim_{x\to 1^-} f(x)\neq \lim_{x\to 1^+} f(x)\neq f(1)$$

Comment: What is the significance of 1−x^2≤1 ? Sorry I'm still a bit confused.

Comment: @Human The idea is that when $x$ becomes small that is $-1<x<1$ we have that $1-x^2$ is samller than $1 $ thus $1-x^2\to 1^-$ that is approaches 1 from below. Then the given limit is equal to the limit for $f(x)$ as $x\to 1^-$.

Comment: Alright thank you very much

Comment: @Human You are welcome! Bye